# How to connect Maxdb to SQL or Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, sap-basis, maxdb

Presently I'm using Maxdb on SAP. I would like to migrated to SQL or Oracle.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is called OS/DB migration (heterogeneous system copy), and must be done by a SAP OS/DB Certified Consultant if you want to have support from your SAP support center.